# Save Userfrom Listbox Contents as PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, listbox, report

Below is the macro assigned to my "Generate Report" CommandButton to save the active worksheet as a pdf file. I am trying to use this macro to save the contents of my userform listbox as a PDF instead. Is this achievable?

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

     With ws.PageSetup
         .CenterHeader = "Asset List"
         .Orientation = xlPortrait
         .Zoom = True
         .FitToPagesTail = False
         .FitToPagesWide = 1
     End With

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Below is how the Userform listbox is populated by using the textboxsearch with search button.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

'ListBox1.Clear
ListBox1.RowSource = ""
ListBox1.ColumnHeads = False

'listbox column headers
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
 For A = 1 To 8
     Me.ListBox1.List(0, A - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, A)
 Next A
 Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True


'Populating listbox1 from search
 Dim i As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Dim SheetList(0 To 1) As String
 Dim k As Integer

SheetList(0) = "Sheet1"
SheetList(1) = "Sheet2"

  For k = LBound(SheetList) To UBound(SheetList)
     Set ws = Sheets(SheetList(k))

     For i = 2 To ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
         For j = 1 To 8
             H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A" & i, "H" & i), ws.Cells(i, j))
             If H = 1 And LCase(ws.Cells(i, j)) = LCase(Me.SearchTextBox) Or H = 1 And _
             ws.Cells(i, j) = Val(Me.SearchTextBox) Then
                 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                 For X = 1 To 8
                     Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, X - 1) = ws.Cells(i, X)
                 Next X
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
 Next k

'Count the listbox rows when populated
 With Me.ListBox1
 For X = 0 To .ListCount - 1
     Total = X
 Next X
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer: *Yes*.  Where is the location of the listbox contents?  If this is a sheet in excel, then you can save that sheet as a pdf, if it's generated via code, you would need to post to a readable location and save that as a pdf.

Comment: Hi Cyril. The listbox is in a userform. The contents are displayed within the listbox when I click on a searchbox. It is generated via code.

Comment: Alright, given that the the listbox is most likely generated from an array in your code, populating the userform1.listbox1, you should be able to append that array to a sheet, then .move that sheet and pdf that file.

Comment: Can you post the code how the listbox is populated?

Comment: Hi Cyril, I have added how my listbox would be populated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a helper sheet so when you append to the listbox (*Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, X - 1) = ws.Cells(i, X)*) that same information is pasted to the helper sheet, to maintain the list allowing you to PDF that sheet.

Something like this should get you to there, inside of your *For X* loop:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row,1).Value = ws.Cells(i, X)
End With
```

Note that in your code you are consolidating a much larger list, so an efficient way to only collect that consolidated list would be to put it in its own location to utilize later.

You can add a loop to your PDF macro to account for this other sheet, such as:

```
Dim i as long, arr as variant
arr = array("Sheet1","Sheet3")
For i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr) 
    With Sheets(arr(i))
        'PDFing macro
    End with
Next i
```

---

**Edit1:**

Hopefully a little more clear (note that you may need to add a sheet to the workbook, as i am arbitrarily using Sheet3):

```
For X = 1 To 8
    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, X - 1) = ws.Cells(i, X)
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row,1).Value = ws.Cells(i, X)
    End With
Next X
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get the 1st code in the answer. Which for X Loop are we talking about?

Comment: @Kev The one which populates the list box, including the line of code in italics from my post (copied it from your code).  Your second for X is just a count, so you wouldn't have the data to put into the helper sheet.

Comment: With Sheets(arr(i)) throws up an error says "it is our of scope"

Comment: @Kev did you change your array to match what you wanted to be looked at (actual sheet names)?  *arr = array("Sheet1","Sheet3")* was an example

Comment: sorry still doesn't work for me as I dont understand where to put the 1st code you supplied within the X loop

Comment: Basically I want a button on my userform that when clicked, it generates a pdf file that contains the contents of my listbox. My listbox can display contents from multiple sheets. So this would be in some kind of array

Comment: @Kev see my edit for where the code would go... the preceding parenthetical statement is very important.

Comment: thank you. But to my original question how can I just save my listbox contents as a pdf. Dont really want to add another worksheet to the workbook as it will be locked down

Comment: @Kev unless you append the data somewhere that can be saved as a pdf, you won't be able.

Comment: Is there any other recommended way to do this? Basically just export the userform listbox contents to a word document, csv, pdf, etc?

Comment: What i had suggested was the helper sheet within excel (keeps one VBA structure); you could also add to a .txt, .csv, .docx, etc.  That's pretty much it... take data from VBA, put it in a readable format (csv/etc.) then use that readable format.